# Fabric js pinch to zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I have a canvas with a bunch of objects in it. I wanted to be able to zoom in on smartphones, so I hooked up  gesture events. Just by adding fabricjs with gestures, i was able to zoom in on individual objects on the canvas. Is it possible to disable  this feature? 
When I zoom in, if i have selected a object, it will get enlarged and also zoom in. This is the function for zooming in:

```
   canvas.on({
        'touch:gesture': function (event) {
            if (event.e.touches && event.e.touches.length == 2) {
                if (event.self.state == "start") {
                    zoomStartScale = canvas.getZoom();
                }

                var delta = zoomStartScale * event.self.scale;

                canvas.setZoom(delta);
                canvas.renderAll();
            }
        }
    });
```